# It keeps showing a problem with CMakeLists.txt

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, pytorch, yolov5

I want to convert onnx to ncnn, when compiling protobuf, I first built a “build” folder in cmake, and used two different folders to put the configuration of  “release” and “debug” respectively：
[image]

The protobuf file directory I downloaded is as follows：
[image]
I have downloaded cmake and git.
[image]
[image]

compile command:
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../../../install  ../..

This problem always occurs when I install protobuf on windows:
[image]

[image]
It keeps showing a problem with CMakeLists.txt
And it shows that there is no path, is it because there is no path?

[image]
If yes, which path to add?

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace.

Comment: The first command is just wrong and the output message explains this. In the second screenshot cmake is trying to find the Visual Studio compiler, but it it doesn't succeed, since either there's no visual studio installed or the compiler wasn't added to the `PATH` environment variable; this is explained rather clearly in the cmake output too. The path for me btw would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.*.*\bin\Hostx*\*`

Comment: I will have a try. Thank you very much.